# Formatting the text response from an AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been working to build my first serverless web application, using AWS Lambda, API Gateway, and S3. The good news is, I've gotten it to work, and everything is talking to each other like I want it to. The bad news is, the text response I get back is ugly, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix it.

Website: http://wmcleanzodiac.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

If you click the button to trigger the function, you'll see the response is written like:

```
{"Your Zodiac sign is :" "result"}
```

I'm trying to remove the quotes and brackets. I tried JSON.parse, but that just yielded object Object. Any hints on where I can look to find a solution?
To get the response, I'm using the following javascript function:

```
    <script>
      function Lambda(){
        var month = document.getElementById("inmonth").value;
        var day = document.getElementById("inday").value;
        var date = {month : month, day : day};
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url= 'https://c50vvxrko9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Zodiac'   

        xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(date));

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var resultElement = $("#sign-result");
            resultElement.text(this.responseText);

          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: how is this `python` related?

Comment: The AWS Lambda function it calls through the API Gateway is written in Python. I put that in just in case it somehow influences the way the results are delivered, or that's where I need to make a change.

Comment: A few minor comments: use `const` (or `let`) rather than `var`, use `{month, day}` rather than `{month : month, day : day}`, use `===` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the whole response into the HTML Element.

To fix this, one way is to modify your lambda to return JSON in Format like: `{"result": "<the_result>"}`.
Then display it using: `resultElement.text(this.responseText.result);` in your javascript code.

Comment: It took a bit of messing with the code both in Lambda and in Javascript to make it work, but it does! Thank you!